# Как работать со сторонним API из Yii2?

Tags: yii2, api

Есть проект на Yii2. Мобильное приложение через API дергает методы и получает ответ.
Возникла необходимось работы с Wowza Streaming Engine у которого есть свой API.
Каким образом, посредством Yii2, можно дергать методы стороннего API?

Не имею понятия в какую сторону копать.
За пример кода буду весьма благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

При работе с любым REST API вы просто посылаете HTTP запросы и принимаете ответ. 
Для этого в Php чаще всего используют библиотеку `curl`, но я сразу порекомендую вам удобную обертку для неё - [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). Пример использования есть прямо в Readme.

Answer (score 0):

Только что нашел родной для Yii2
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient

Работает исправно, и довольно быстро.